# Read excel files with capybara or selenium

Tags: selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am testing an application where you can respond to a survey. Survey results are then entered into an excel file and the survey admin can then download this file and see the results. I wish to be able to automate the testing of this.

I can respond to the survey and download the file no problem. However is there a way I can then open the downloaded file and read and verify the contents of it? Currently use rspec/capybara for our testing so I would like to find a solution that uses these or perhaps I can drop down to the selenium level?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Yes you can do it with java. you need to find the downloaded file by using folder option. and you can read the file after getting its name.

Comment: Selenium will only be good to fill out the survey.  After that, it is out of Selenium's control, since all Selenium does is `"automate browsers"`. You'll have to find an ruby excel library to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the downloaded file name, you can use the below code(Java):

Do import these files:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

File folder = new File(download_path);

    File[] listOfFilesBeforeDownload = folder.listFiles();
    for(File x: listOfFilesBeforeDownload){
        System.out.println("Files before download:"+x);

        }

//Download the file now

    File[] listOfFilesAfterDownload = folder.listFiles();

    for(File x: listOfFilesAfterDownload){
        String xx=x.toString();
        if(xx.contains(".crdownload")){

        }

    }

    listOfFilesAfterDownload = folder.listFiles();
    for(File x: listOfFilesAfterDownload){
        System.out.println("Files after download:"+x);

        }

    boolean contains = false;    
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int m=0; m<listOfFilesAfterDownload.length; m++) {

        for(int n=0; n<listOfFilesBeforeDownload.length; n++) {


            String afterFileName=listOfFilesAfterDownload[m].getName();
            String beforeFileName=listOfFilesBeforeDownload[n].getName();
            if(afterFileName.equals(beforeFileName)) {

                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!contains) {
        filename=listOfFilesAfterDownload[m].getName();
            results.add(filename);

        }
        else{
            //System.out.println(" contains = false");
            contains = false;
        }           
    }        
    System.out.println(results);
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println("filename : "+filename);
```

After getting the file name you can extract the contents from the file. Something like this,

```
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(download+fname+"");
           // POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fis); 


            org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor oleTextExtractor 
= new XWPFWordExtractor(new XWPFDocument(fis));
            String content=oleTextExtractor.getText();
```

Comment: One thing the original poster failed to mention: capybara is ruby. Your code, however correct, will probably not be useful to OP.

Comment: Hey Guys - thanks for the responses. Yeah, should have mentioned that caypbara is ruby but ill look for a way to do it with the java example above.